# Pressure being equal in a vessel

Tags: homework-and-exercises, ideal-gas

An open vessel at $27^{\circ} C$ is heated until $\frac{3}{5}$ of the air in it has been expelled. Assuming that the volume of the vessel remains constant, find the temperature to which the vessel has been heated.

In the solution given,they said that the pressure remains unchanged along with the volume. I did not get this,so i looked up more in the internet and found that the reason is because the same atmospheric pressure works here. I have a few questions regarding this,

In equilibrium condition,we know internal pressure of the gas=external pressure. So in the formula $PV=nRT$, $P$ can be both external pressure and internal pressure. Now, *what makes open vessel the only case when external pressure(which in this case is atmospheric pressure) is equal?* Why is this not the same for closed vessels? Since the same atmospheric pressure is being applied all over the container and in open vessel also the same atmospheric pressure works on the container.

So it would follow that in all containers,the pressure will always remain constant.

Comment: If the vessel is open we have the same pressure inside and outside. If the vessel is closed, its walls can withstand a pressure difference, so the pressure inside can be different from the pressure outside. If you have a closed vessel with 1 atm inside, at 27°C, the pressure inside is equal to the pressure outside, but this situation changes when you change the temperature. Please clarify the question if this explanation is not what you are asking for.

Comment: Thanks for commenting,could you please explain why changing temperature will result in the change of situation?And also what is the pressure difference that you have mentioned?Regards.

Comment: @Bob D Since the vessel is open,won't the air expel by itself?

Comment: You need to approach this problem using Dalton's law of partial pressures.

Answer (score -1):

You need to approach the problem by using Dalton's law of partial pressures. The partial pressure of each ideal gas component of a mixture of gases is the pressure that it alone would exert if it occupied the same volume.  Then the partial pressure of each gas is equal to the total absolute pressure (in this case 1 atm for an open vessel) times the volume fraction of the gas component.

So in your example two gas components are dry air and water vapor (gaseous $H_{2}O$), both assumed to be ideal gases. The volume fractions after heating are are 0.6 for the water vapor component and 0.4 for the dry air component. Thus the partial pressure of the water vapor is 0.6 x the total pressure of 1 atm, or 0.6 x 101 kPa = 60.6 kPa.

To find the temperature where this occurs consult the saturated water tables to determine the saturation temperature corresponding to the saturation pressure of 60.6 kPa using linear interpolation.

Hope this helps.